# world in a dewdrop

Tags: story-identification, novel

Novel where final paragraphs zoom out to reveal that entire world of story has taken place in a universe contained in a drop of dew on a leaf or blade of grass in the garden of an older couple, who I believe were British. Can anyone identify this novel?

Answer (score 6):

It's James Blish's "Surface Tension".

Plot summary from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_Tension_%28short_story%29):

> A human colonization ship crash-lands on a distant planet which is earth-like but whose only landmass is completely covered in shallow puddles of water and mostly microscope life forms. Normal humans could not survive on this planet, so the crew must genetically engineer their descendants into something that can survive. (Blish coined the term pantropy to refer to this concept.) They decide to create a race of microscopic aquatic humanoids to complete their mission and colonize the planet.
>
> The majority of the story concerns one groups of these genetically engineered colonists and their intelligence, curiosity, and evolving technology. In particular, the tiny aquatic humanoids develop a "space ship", or rather "air ship", which enables them to pierce the previously impenetrable surface tension of the water and travel through what is, to them, hostile space—open air—to other worlds in other puddles of water.

Comment: This story does explicitly *not* contain the part of the OP's question about the drop of water being in a British garden.  Surface Tension took place on a distant planet.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like one of those stories:

- [**The Diamond Lens**](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/23169/23169-h/23169-h.htm) by [Fitz James O'Brien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitz_James_O%27Brien)

  > “The Diamond Lens” is probably his most famous short story, and tells the story of a scientist who invents a powerful microscope and discovers a beautiful female in a microscopic world inside a drop of water
- [**The Drop of Water**](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhca.gilead.org.il%2Fdrop_wat.html&ei=Ht68U8rzCpCV7AaLmIGwCg&usg=AFQjCNGUcHHpPHD9vD4SwYfvCmyWBbzqqg&sig2=s0XNrw7MZWUR5rUuQVElvw) by [Hans Christian Andersen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Christian_Andersen)

  > The man looking through the microscope is named Cribbley Crabbey and he watches the little creatures tear each other apart in a drop of puddle water.